# basic Inheritance in XNA C#

Tags: c#, xna, timespan

I'm trying to expand System.TimeSpan in C# because I need a extra method to convert the GameTime to a TimeSpan. This is what i tried:

```
class TimeSpanner : TimeSpan
{
}
```

apperently it's not possible to extend the Timespan struct. Does anyone know why it can't be extended? And how do I properly make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're taking completely the wrong approach. `GameTime` has member properties `ElapsedGameTime` and `TotalGameTime` that provide the two different `TimeSpan`s that make up a `GameTime` object. Use them like this:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    TimeSpan elapsed = gameTime.ElapsedGameTime;
    TimeSpan total = gameTime.TotalGameTime;

    // Personally, I just do this:
    float seconds = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not inherit from a `struct`.

Form MSDN on [structs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> There is no inheritance for structs as there is for classes. A struct cannot inherit from another struct or class, and it cannot be the base of a class. Structs, however, inherit from the base class Object. A struct can implement interfaces, and it does that exactly as classes do.

As an alternative to what you are trying, consider using [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

A TimeSpan is a `struct` and structs (which are a value type) cannot be subclassed.  You should probably investigate using an operator to perform a conversion.

You could do something like this:

```
public static implicit operator TimeSpan(GameTime gt) 
{
    return gt.GetTimeSpan();
}
```

You could then use this like this:

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = (TimeSpan)myGameTime;
```

Comment: The conversion should be marked explicit rather than implicit if going down this route.

Comment: And where would you put this conversion operator? `TimeSpan` and `GameTime` are both framework classes (.NET and XNA respectively).

Answer (score 1):

If you need an extra method to do a conversion then why not just make an extension method then?

```
public static void DoStuff(this TimeSpan timeSpan, GameTime gameTime)
{
     ...
}
```

Comment: The extension method you've given isn't suitable for doing a conversion.